# SFMC Journey - Data binding pulling a value from a DE with multiple rows for contact

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder, marketing-cloud-connect, databinding

I have included the VAWP url in my Send Log DE as well as the name of the email sent. Obviously I have multiple emails being sent to the same Contacts throughout a week. I am attempting to use data binding to grab the right record in my DE to write into a SFDC Task create activity in my Journey.

**Requirement**:  I want to create a SFDC Task in a JB Activity and put the url to the VAWP link in the activity so that my SFDC Users can see the email that was sent to the Contact and refer to in Service Cloud cases.

```
{{#switch}} 
{{.when Contact.Attribute."SendLog_Email"."emailname_" == Interaction."EMAIL_ACTIVITY_NAME"}}
{{Contact.Attribute."Contacts"."SendLog_Email"."view_email_url"}} 
{{/switch}}
```

In my head this data binding should use the Data Designer to find the Contact row(s) in the 'SendLog_Email' send log DE, then use this #switch logic to find the correct record for the Email that was sent in the email activity in-front of the Task creation activity. So the pathing is simply like this:

[image: visual representation of Journey path]

Still new to data binding and making sure the 'Interaction.Activity_Name' is correct syntax and this will work as I expect it to, anyone have a better solution to this use case?

Comment: UPDATE: 

Looks like the #switch function is not supported in Journey Builder Activities, at lease SFDC Activities. Message from support when I ran the above code in a test Journey: 

Error code : ExactTarget.InteractionStudio.Engine.EngineUnhandledRuntimeException
Status : Fail
Message : Encountered an unknown tag: {{#switch}}. It was either not registered or exists in a different context.

It seems like the error was due to the {{#switch}} used within the description of the task and salesforce have marked this as an unknown or unrecognized tag .